# Service Reference in Silverlight don't show all of functions defined in WCF Service

Tags: c#, database, wcf, silverlight

I want to retrieve data from a database using a WCF service and service reference in my Silverlight project. All things that I do are:

1. created Linq-to-SQL file and add server connection then drag some table from server explorer to `PersonDataClass.dbml` file
2. Create WCF service

   [image]
3. Implemented the functions defined in the interface:

   [image]
4. created a Service Reference named `DBServicesRef`

   but in my code I can access just one function of the WCF Service, just the `getPersonComplete` service method :

[image]

I searched the web but I am beginner in Silverlight :)

I clean, build, rebuild the project, update `DBServiceRef` (with check or uncheck reuse type in referenced assemblies ) or even delete and create files but I can not insert any value to database :( because I can not access the `addPersonComplete` service method to handle it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addPersonRecord` does not return any value. Therefor it will not get it's own event handler. It will use a generic handler.
When you've written the `+=` after `webService.addPersonCompleted` just press tab twice and you should get a new function with the correct signature automatically.